# Forcing communication of an IOT client to a server

Tags: node.js, server, iot

I have an IoT client that is connected to a server via wifi. I want to force all communication of the IoT client to go to the server first. Right now, I am connecting the 2 via socket io but when i run a http request code on the IoT to google, the device does not communicate through the server but straight to google. How do I prevent this. Do i change the wifi connection between the IoT and server to something else?

Comment: It seems that you want to use a server as a proxy in this scenario. Firstly you need  to implement the server which include proxy function. And then configure the http proxy in your system.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Ill be looking into setting up a proxy server. Im using a raspberry pi as my client, to configure the http proxy server as the default path for any requests my device is doing,  do I have to configure the iptables of my device, or write a script that whenever the device sends a message the destination ip is changed to the proxy server?

Comment: What system is running on your raspberry pi, Windows IoT Core or Linux?

Comment: Raspbian which is linux based.

Answer (score 0):

In Raspbian for **general browsing**, you can add following command in `/etc/environment`.

```
export http_proxy="http://username:password@host:port/"
```

For apt-get, you can add commands in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10proxy`.

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@host:port";
```

But if there are other communications except http protocol, you need to config the proxy in your app and implement all the service in the proxy.